# KeyError Traceback (most recent call last): Panda dataframe, url as variable

Tags: python, pandas, url

I'm getting this error.
urls is a list of urls.
Something like this: urls = ['url1', 'url2', ...]
What is strange is that I get this error for some urls but not for others.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-b65ca12b2fa6> in <module>
      9 # using STOP as a marker to split lists
     10 for url in urls:
---> 11     df_select_url = df.groupby('URL').get_group(url)
     12     list_brand.append("STOP")
     13     list_brand.append(url)

/Applications/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in get_group(self, name, obj)
    684         inds = self._get_index(name)
    685         if not len(inds):
--> 686             raise KeyError(name)
    687 
    688         return obj._take_with_is_copy(inds, axis=self.axis)

KeyError: 'https://onegivenurlineedtokeepcondifential.com'
```

Comment: This might be happening becauseyour dataframe doesn't have that particular URL.

Comment: Seems to be the case!